# SDL keyboard strange behaviors

Tags: c++, sdl

Only function keys get caught by SDL_KEYDOWN and they get printed normally , normal letters and numbers sometimes get caught by  SDL_TEXTINPUT(unpredictably) but when i try to print them i get either nothing or things like "Æëçó" , the key dosen't get caught at all by the if statement . Does anyone have the same problem ?

This is on win 10 Visual Studio 19 and i get the same results when using on screen keyboard .

```
switch (g_event->type)
    {
        case SDL_KEYDOWN: //here only ctrl , alt , caps get caught
            std::cout << SDL_GetKeyName(g_event->key.keysym.sym); //this prints out the names correctly
            break;
        case SDL_TEXTINPUT: //here normal keys get caught sometimes(letters,numbers...)
            std::cout << SDL_GetKeyName(g_event->key.keysym.sym); //this prints out things like this "ⁿÆëçó" or nothing at all
            if(g_event->key.keysym.sym==SDLK_f)   //the key isn't caught no matter what
            {std::cout<<"f";}
            break;
    }
```

Comment: How is this different from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63421385/letters-and-numbers-dont-get-caught-by-event-in-sdl2)? ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAnZ7.png))

Comment: My previous post had no code at all at first (even though i don't think it was needed) and because of that it got "hidden", it isn't visible so my question can't be answered .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would not access g_event.key.keysym.sym in a SDL_TEXTINPUT event.
It gives you a parameter as g_event.text.text where you have the inputed text as a char array.